# Can you run C file and header file in swift playgrounds on iPad?

Tags: swift, ipad, swift-playground

I wanted to make a VNC project on swift playgrounds on iPad but it includes C files . Is there any way of importing these and runnning them in the playground app on iPad ?

Comment: I'm really curious if that's possible, did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope couldnt do that. But maybe recent update to Swift Playgrounds may allow that